# csv to core data method error 2012

Tags: ios, core-data, csv

I have read a few posts and found a method.  I adapted it to my app, however at [self saveContext]; I get a bad instruction error.

Please let me know why, and if this method makes sense. Also I am using \r because in the csv each item is in its own row.

Thank you in advance

```
-(void)addData{
    NSString *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *bundlePath = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"coredatainfo.csv"];
    NSString *dataFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];
    NSArray *dataRows = [dataFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
    [dataFile release];
    FirstCDitem *myItem;


    for (int i = 0 ; i < [dataRows count] ; i++)
    {
        NSArray *dataElements = [[dataRows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"Added: %d %@",i,dataElements);
        myItem = (FirstCDitem *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FirstCDitem" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        [FirstCDitem setTitle:[dataElements objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self saveContext];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in this code line:

```
[FirstCDitem setTitle:[dataElements objectAtIndex:i]];
```

- `i` is the current *row number*, so it probably makes no sense to use it as index to the `dataElements` array. Perhaps you want the first element in the row?
- `setTitle` must sent to the instance `myItem`, not to the class `FirstCDItem`.

So the line should look like this:

```
[myItem setTitle:[dataElements objectAtIndex:0]];
```